# call contract function signed on client side web3.js 1.0

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

I don't think the web3.js 1.0 docs cover this.

I found this post. but the answer seems outdated.
[How to properly create a raw transaction and sign it using web3 in browser](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36358/how-to-properly-create-a-raw-transaction-and-sign-it-using-web3-in-browser)

**I'd like to use web3.js 1.0 the future is now.**

what i have so far:

```
var web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/<top secret>');
var abi = <abi things>
var address = <contract address>
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,address);
myContract.methods.getmessage().call().then(console.log);
```

Comment: @Jaime you are right. but how else could i get a new answer to an old question? i think it deserves a 2018 web.js 1.0 answer.

Comment: I understand you. I changed the answer as to how to do this with web3 1.0, let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follow in web3 1.0 as explained [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction)

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
dataTx = myContract.methods.mymethod(params).encodeABI(); //The encoded ABI of the method

var rawTx = {
  to: 'yourcantract address', 
  data:dataTx 
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign('yourprivateKey');

var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
.on('receipt', console.log);
```

Comment: buildTransaction is not a function. the web3.js 1.0 docs have no mention of it. i don't think its the same like in python(the link you pointed me to)

Comment: You are right, the code below is for web3py. I deleted that and I will updated it as soon as possible.

Comment: Please check the updated answer and let me know.

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` for the first line in your snippet. Any help?

Comment: john, the issue is that you seem to be running this in a webpage and require is not a valid function of the client side, this assumes you are using a server. If you want to do this on the client side you should [try something like this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8579/how-to-use-ethereumjs-tx-js-in-a-browser)