# How to use "web3.js library" in a "JavaScript" file without using "require("web3")"?

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethereumjs, signature, browsers

Consider we want to use `web3.personal.sign` in a `JavaScript` file. So, we need to add :

```
Web3 = require("web3")
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

at top of our `JavaScript` file.

However, if we want to run this code in a `browser`, we cannot use `require()`. For example, in case of using `ethereumjs` we can add github resources as follows (as described in [THIS ANSWER](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/23532/23024)):

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds/2fb69a714afe092b06645286f14b94f41e5c062c/dist/ethereumjs-tx.js"></script>
<script>
```

**And It works.**

So, is there a similar way for adding `web3.js` using `<script src= ...` ?

**When I use** `<script src="https://rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js"</script> <script>` **instead of** `Web3 = require("web3")` I receive following error message :

```
    <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EthereumJS - Browser Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds/master/dist/ethereumjs-abi/ethereumjs-abi-0.6.5.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

  <script>



  function constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount) 
  {
  return ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256"],
    [contractAddress, amount],
  );
  }

  var message = constructPaymentMessage("0x0f0f422477d83bcbed227b0ae2fa3ace7ea3c653", 100);
  console.log(message);

  web3.personal.sign("0x" + message.toString("hex"), "0xc9c3b1351c65ac47abf3774b6a9715ba3625bec5",  function(err, something) {});

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

> ***"test.html:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: web3 is not defined at test3.html:28"***

**Note1:** `test.html` is name of this `html` file.

**Note2:** I use `web3 version 1.0.0`.

**Note3:**  My **main purpose** is to run successfully `JavaScript` code presented [HERE](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/) . When I run it using `node` I receive some errors. What is the best way of running this `JavaScript` code? Do I need to create an `html` file and run it with `browser`? or it's better to create a `JavaScript` file and run it using `node filename.js` ? The problem with running this code that is for signature verification is explained in details [HERE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/updated-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-revert) . Eventually, I had to change some part of `JavaScript` code (I precised which parts have been changed in my question [HERE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/updated-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-revert) ). However, eventually, when I call the function of `Solidity` contract (i.e. `function close`) to verify `signature`, the transaction is **reverted** as I mentioned the details of error [HERE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/updated-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-revert).

**Note4:** Related question: [web3.js error: Cannot read property 'providers' of undefined](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54876/web3-js-error-cannot-read-property-providers-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

Adding `<script src="https://rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js"</script>` to replace `Web3 = require("web3")` is correct, but you still need to establish a Web3 provider like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name)
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        console.log('No Web3 Detected... using HTTP Provider')
        window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/<APIKEY>"));
    }
})
```

The Web3 provider is what actually connects your JavaScript to the Ethereum network so you can make calls. After that, you will be able to start calling `web3` functions.

Take a look at this ["Hello world" tutorial for Web3.js](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/ethereum/ethereum-web3-js-hello-world-get-eth-balance-ethereum-address/).

Comment: That hello world link no longer works

Comment: I have updated the link. Please let me know if you find issues with the tutorial today, since it has been a while since I wrote it

Answer (score 0):

you can use Infura services. infura provide the web3.
first you have to create acc in infura after that you should make project. and at least you can use your own Id in this code : `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/3c68ea1...your ID...f301753"));` 
also you can use main net or ropsten network.
please check [site](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-setup-your-dapps-to-not-use-metamask-plugin-but-sign-the-transaction-backend-b8cb8808c9ae)
and this is [infura site](https://infura.io/)

Comment: The question was how to include web3.js in a project. I wasn't about using it, just how to include in the html file.