# web3.js error: Cannot read property 'providers' of undefined

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethereumjs, web3-providers, browsers

What is problem of this simple `html` / `JavaScript` / `ethreumjs` / `web3.js` code?

```
    <!doctype html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>EthereumJS - Browser Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <script src="https://rawgit.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds/master/dist/ethereumjs-abi/ethereumjs-abi-0.6.5.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script> 

      <script>

      var abi = new ethereumjs.ABI()
      var Web3 
      web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I run this code I receive the following error in `Console` of `browser` in `line 17` of this code (i.e. `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers...`) :

> ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'providers' of undefined at
>   test.html:17***

**Note:** Please note that I **cannot** use `Web3 = require("web3")` , because I receive following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: Please note that I cannot use Web3 = require("web3") , because I receive following error:

As per the documentation for including `web3` as a [browser module](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/#as-browser-module) (which you're already doing for the ABI code):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, now I do not receive error, However, I cannot see **signature value** that I explain the question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54883/how-to-see-output-of-web3-personal-sign-in-browser Thanks