# "Updated :" How to see "output" of "web3.personal.sign" in "browser"? ("Method personal_sign not supported")

Tags: web3js, metamask, testrpc, javascript, signature

**Note: *I updated the `html` / `JavaScript` code according to the answer and I used [THIS META MASK sample code](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md) for web3 provider. However, I receive the same error. I eventually did not understand that do I need run testRPC or not ?*.**

I run following `html` `JavaScript` code to generate a signature **after running** `testRPC` and using **Meta Mask** as follows:

(1) run `testRPC` :

```
PS C:\Users\s> testrpc
EthereumJS TestRPC v6.0.3 (ganache-core: 2.0.2

Available Accounts
==================
(0) 0xf4d2b942c3baebef5b81f4b909904015166b238a
(1) 0xef0d1e102d33252f232b39b31950f736ab2535aa
(2) 0x23064a138dc6b681a51a18b837a376f061fbc511
(3) 0x2dfaf5c48bc3c868f63741d6cd0489b336e74b03
(4) 0x372110011158860806d9d9b19aa67c045740727a
(5) 0x3faa74be50e1dfa86e5f6951a8c11b3e726edf65
(6) 0xaecc4c8f0b802b83a2cd84e6c98ecad6b0495c00
(7) 0x36b08ae47ec94870b98b0e0d98fca2646332ae87
(8) 0x1461cfb91f6fd2aca8d722dce9f67f7806732e49
(9) 0x1a0b2fd11e57f6473ae5f9b55e17cbfb6d8b504e

Private Keys
==================
(0) acb8b8ee76ce99fc390127ae88e246d3f8d8ac3db7
(1) 8957622705ccec21da4791f8535c70ab4726bfbe08
(2) 41181e3cf8c0294e949062a894bd96aea15e342db5
(3) c1bad63470c62b56032b034df0f0b827779e678cfd
(4) f49109620e9e56aa0bff9bdeb486d05ca75732cf1a
(5) ed1107372972a702c166924846f6d01234b9d277a7
(6) 10afce272e6a3d1d3474c385bf28be7e58de991995
(7) 0a92c9aa01497d29f01023cdeb50429954be06c949
(8) 87d0c56f9cab4c86ebc66749d0894719b647f72cea
(9) c8ca68e445b249a7d860fc3d76b210d6dd1a1c2197

HD Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:      access invest retire civil eagl
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}
```

(2) selecting `0xf4d2b942c3baebef5b81f4b909904015166b238a` as signer address.

(3) adding `0xf4d2b942c3baebef5b81f4b909904015166b238a` to **Meta Mask**.

(4) running following `html` / `JavaScript` code in `Google Chrome` :

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EthereumJS - Browser Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds/master/dist/ethereumjs-abi/ethereumjs-abi-0.6.5.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

  <script>

window.addEventListener('load', function() {

   // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }

//  var Web3 
//  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

  function constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount) 
  {
  return ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256"],
    [contractAddress, amount],
  );
  }

  var message = constructPaymentMessage("0x0f0f422477d83bcbed227b0ae2fa3ace7ea3c653", 100);
  console.log(message);

  web3.personal.sign("0x" + message.toString("hex"), "0xF4D2B942c3baebef5B81F4B909904015166b238A", function(err, signature) {
  console.log(signature);
  console.log(err);
  // Be sure to make use of the signature only here.
  // It will not be defined until this callback is invoked.
});

}) 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following is the result :

[image]

Pleas note that

`Uint8Array(32) [2, 16, 48, 216, 191, 103, 173, 178, 132, 121, 144, 241, 45, 224, 83, 239, 76, 206, 69, 151, 42, 86, 174, 144, 3, 97, 172, 171, 166, 231, 234, 10]`

is the `message` value and result of `console.log(message);` and not **signature value** and when I use `console.log(signature);` the output is only `undefined`.

*How can I see **signature value** ?*

And the following is the error message, result of `console.log(err);` :

> **Error: Method personal_sign not supported**

```
Error: Error: Method personal_sign not supported.
    at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:89858:16)
    at next (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:59378:18)
    at GethDefaults.handleRequest (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:89767:12)
    at next (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:59378:18)
    at FilterSubprovider.handleRequest (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:65832:7)
    at next (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:59378:18)
    at DelayedBlockFilter.handleRequest (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:89595:3)
    at next (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:59378:18)
    at ReactiveBlockTracker.handleRequest (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:89722:12)
    at next (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:59378:18)
    at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:89858:16)
    at next (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:59378:18)
    at GethDefaults.handleRequest (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:89767:12)
    at next (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:59378:18)
    at FilterSubprovider.handleRequest (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:65832:7)
    at next (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:59378:18)
    at DelayedBlockFilter.handleRequest (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:89595:3)
    at next (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:59378:18)
    at ReactiveBlockTracker.handleRequest (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:89722:12)
    at next (C:\Users\s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:59378:18)
    at Object.InvalidResponse (https://rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js:3138:16)
    at https://rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js:6375:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (https://rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js:4377:7)
```

*Related question:* ["UPDATED : " "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/updated-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-revert)

Comment: There is no reason to include "web3.js" and "web3.min.js". They are the same thing.

Comment: @Shawn Tabrizi Do you mean I can remove one of them ? Thanks

Comment: Yes. You should probably only be using the `web3.min.js` file unless you want to look at the source code. See [Minification (programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming))

Comment: @Shawn Tabrizi  According to comment of `smarx` I need to add `MetaMast web3 provider` in the code. Does it mean I need to replace `HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))` by something else ? Thanks

Comment: `window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);` Check out my answer to your other question

Comment: @Shawn Tabrizi I update my code according to this `MetaMask` sample code : https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md However, if i am connected to `testrpc` i receive the same error i.e. `Method personal_sign not supported` because `testrpc` does not support it and if i am NOT connected to `testrpc` i receive this error : ` http://localhost:8545/ 0 ()` (screen shot : https://ibb.co/dFRQpJ)  Thanks

Comment: fyi: since `1.0.0-beta.38`, `web3.eth.personal.sign` no longer accepts an `undefined` value for the third argument (password for the account).

Answer (score 1):

The signature is sent to your callback, which is empty in the code you shared. This should work:

```
web3.personal.sign("0x" + message.toString("hex"), "0xF4D2B942c3baebef5B81F4B909904015166b238A", function(err, signature) {
  console.log(signature);
  // Be sure to make use of the signature only here.
  // It will not be defined until this callback is invoked.
});
```

As an aside, note that your current code does *not* use MetaMask.

Comment: @smartx Thank you, I replaced it, However, it's still `undefined`. Btw, in `testrpc` terminal I receive `eth_getBlockByNumber` one after another, it can be a problem ? Thanks

Comment: Here is the testrpc output : https://ibb.co/fZHUid Thanks

Comment: Then try printing out the `err`.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question. Now `err` is `Error: Method personal_sign not supported`. why? Thanks

Comment: `testrpc` doesn't support the method `personal_sign`. You'll need to use geth, Parity, MetaMask, or something else that does support that method.

Comment: Thank you, I am using `MetaMask` and after running `testrpc` I connect `MetaMask` to `private network` `(localhost 8545)`. but without running `testrpc` I am not able to connect to `localhost 8545` using `MetaMask`. How can I solve this problem ? Thanks again

Comment: Your code needs to use the MetaMask web3 provider. You're instead connecting directly to `testrpc`. And yes, of course you need to run `testrpc` for MetaMask to be able to connect to it.

Comment: Thank you, So do you mean I need to replace `HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))` with something else for `MetaMast web3 proviver` ? if so, could you please let me know what is `MetaMast provider` that must be inserted in `HttpProvider(" ? "))` ? Thanks

Comment: The MetaMask documentation will help.

Comment: Thank you, I used this sample code of MetaMask from here: [link](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md) is it what you mean as MetaMask documentation ? I updated my question, however, I receive the same error. Thanks

Comment: In fact, if I am connected to `testRPC` I receive previous error message and if I am not connected to `testRPC` i receive this error : `web3.js:4386 OPTIONS http://localhost:8545/ 0 ()` meaning that I am not connected to `MetaMast provider` . I am really confused ..... Thanks

Comment: Here is screen shot of error when I am not connected to `testrpc` : https://ibb.co/dFRQpJ I finally did not understand that i need to run `testrpc` for this `javascript` code or not ? Thank you

Comment: Yes, as I said, you need to run testrpc. Is it running?

Comment: Thank you, Yes, if it's running I receive the previous error : `personal_sign not supported` and when I stop it, I receive another error : here is screen shot of error when `testrpc` is NOT running: https://ibb.co/dFRQpJ . So, in both cases i receive an error. maybe testing `Ropsten` would be better .... i do not know. Please check out my new code, since i modified it. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to MetaMask? Do you see the console message "No web3? ..."?

Comment: Here is the steps I do: (1) running `testrpc`. (2) click on MetaMask icon and selecting `localhost 8545` (3) select one of `private keys` generated by `testrpc` (4) selecting `import account` from MetaMask and paste this `private key` in `Paste your private key string here` (5) now balance of this address is `100 eth` (6) paste this `address` (public key) in `web3.personal.sign ...` (7) opening`html` file by `Google Chrome` (8) receiving this messages : `No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!` & `Error: Method personal_sign not supported`.screen shot: https://ibb.co/i93oRy .Thx

Comment: is something missing in my steps ? because apparently it's not connected to MetaMask. Thanks

Comment: This answer : (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46400/23024) says that I have to use `https://mainnet.infura.io/<APIKEY>`. is the problem related to to run my page locally ? (According to this answer) Thanks

Comment: That message means you're not using MetaMask. (MetaMask didn't inject `web3`, so it was `undefined`.) If you're running your page from a `file://` URL, then yes, this is the problem. You need to run from an `http://` or `https://` URL. Running locally is fine, but it needs to be via a web server, not the filesystem.

Comment: Thank you, so in this case, I have to use ex. `Parity` to connect to ex. `Ropsten` and then use `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));` in top of `JavaScript` code and running this `JS` file using `node filename.js` ? Is there any better way? Thanks

Comment: No. You can just run testrpc and then open your web page on an `http://` URL. Any web server will do.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80555/discussion-on-answer-by-smarx-updated-how-to-see-output-of-web3-personal).