# Transferring an ERC-20 using web3js 1.0.0

Tags: web3js, erc-20, javascript, raw-transaction

I have been trying to follow the `web3js` documentation, but it mentions things that are not native to Javascript like "Buffer" so I found a library called `ethereumjs-tx` to let me use that.

- My HTML page to test it on has scripts to import `web3js-1.0.0` and         `browser-ethereumjs-tx.js`
- I am using Infura as my web3 provider

Here is my function, with addresses and private keys stripped for safety:

```js
async function transferTokens(){
    // example: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24828/how-to-send-erc20-token-using-web3-api

    // the ABI of the erc20
    var abi;

    // the token address for the specific token 
    var tokenAddr;

    // instantiate the token contract using the ABI and the Contract Address.
    var tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, tokenAddr);

    // who has the tokens to be sent? 
    var sender;

    // where are the tokens being sent?
    var tokenRecipient = document.getElementById('tokenRecipient').value;

    // how many tokens are being sent?
    var tokenAmount;

    // nonce
    var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender);

    //set a gas price for the transfer in GWei (I picked 30 arbitrarily).
    var gasPriceGwei = 30;

    var gasLimit = 400000; // arbitrary, I know it's higher than needed

    //Creating a raw Tx...
    var rawTransaction = {
        "from": sender,
        "nonce": "0x" + count.toString(16), 
        "gasPrice": gasPriceGwei,
        "gasLimit": gasLimit,
        "to": tokenRecipient,
        "value": "0x0",
        "data": tokenContract.methods.transfer(tokenRecipient, tokenAmount).encodeABI(), // not sure wtf
        "chainId": 0x04 //rinkeby network
    };

    // EthJS allows us a buffer function.
    var privKey = new EthJS.Buffer.Buffer('[my_privKey]', 'hex');

    var tx = new EthJS.Tx(rawTransaction); 
    tx.sign(privKey);
    var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

    // Comment out these three lines if you don't really want to send the TX right now
    console.log(`Attempting to send signed tx:  ${serializedTx.toString('hex')}`);
    var receipt =  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));
    console.log(`Receipt info:  ${JSON.stringify(receipt, null, '\t')}`);

}
```

Nothing happens. The console logs:

```
    TEST.html:134 Attempting to send signed tx:  [a Tx that is 334 characters long] 
    TEST.html:136 Receipt info:  {}
```

When I try to include another function (that I know works) inside `transferTokens` with console logs, they never get logged. So presumably the function is never executed for some reason. My working function is:

```js
tokenContract.methods.balanceOf(sender).call(function(err, bal){
    console.log("LOG X");
    if(!err){
        bal = web3.utils.fromWei(bal, 'ether');
        console.log("sender bal: "+bal);
        document.getElementById('balBeforeSending').innerHTML 
        = "The balance of "+ document.getElementById('tokenTransfer').options[document.getElementById('tokenTransfer').selectedIndex].innerHTML
            + " before sending " + sender + " was: " 
            + bal;  
    }
    else{
        console.log("line 106");
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```

I have placed it just before the "creating Raw Transaction" line in the original function.

I had `await` on both the count and the receipt previously but they never got logged so I thought I would remove them. The program was stuck waiting for them but never got anything back so I believe nothing after the `await` was executed.

Comment: If you're connected to an actual public network, I think your gas price is way too low to get a transaction mined. You're passing 30 wei when it should be something like 1 or 2 gwei (2000000000 wei). And yes, you should have `receipt = await ...`.

Comment: @smarx Thank you. I fixed that and actually got it to work based on a previous answer from [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8579/how-to-use-ethereumjs-tx-js-in-a-browser) using their EthJS to allow me to use a buffer and a TX. I know from your site and on here that you are very knowledgeable and helpful so I wonder if you think of any better way I should be able to get Buffer and Tx to work in my browser script. I tell all my colleagues I am learning off stackexchange and programtheblockchain.com. :)

Answer (score 0):

Web3 1.0 isn't actually released yet, which might be why you're having some issues. See the [disclaimer here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/). Instead, use the [API docs here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) to craft your transactions.

And since you added a question on the line where you were generating data for the transaction, in web3 0.x.x you'd need to do something like this to correctly encode the data:

`const data = contractInstance.methodName.getData(param1 [, param2, ...])`

Comment: There is some functionality that our application will need that is only available in v 1.0 (such as creating wallets), so I think I need to be using v1.0 going forward. And for the sake of being up to date, is it not a good idea to be going for 1.0 asap? 
Thanks so much for responding.

Comment: That depends I guess on whether you need something working now or not, and whether you're happy to be at the mercy of web3 1.0's timeline. Can you shoot for an MVP using Web3 0.x, and develop along side it the 1.0.0 functionality to be ready for its release?