# Transaction api question for using remote Node such as infura

Tags: external-api

I want to have a function to send eth to another address by php program, and I do not want to run a local node on my server. Can I use infura as the web3 provider and use the API to send eth to another address?
That means, can I use infura as the node, not using my own local node. I heard that I must sign the message offline? can I directly call infura API to sign? or any easy PHP script for sign and send transaction without running a local node?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use infura, but you need to sign the messages locally and send a raw transaction. Infura's nodes will not allow you to store your keys in there (and you shouldn't).  Another option is to use metamask, which is using infura nodes, but it will take care of the signing locally.

You will find how to sign locally described in this answer: [how to use ethereumjs-tx.js in a browser](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8579/how-to-use-ethereumjs-tx-js-in-a-browser)

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, actually metamask needs a plugin to be installed so it cannot be used for cell phone. As for the signing message locally, is easy any easy php script to use for generating raw transaction? thanks or is there any other node api that allows me to submit my private key so that I can sign the transaction by their api?

Comment: signing the transaction using javascript is easy, see how to do it here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8579/how-to-use-ethereumjs-tx-js-in-a-browser

Comment: Thanks a lot. i checked the site https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8579/how-to-use-ethereumjs-tx-js-in-a-browser, let serializedTx = tx.serialize().toString('hex')

  console.log('serializedTx:', serializedTx), here whether serializedTx will be the raw transaction and will be sent to infura api ? thanks